# Are my thoughts on the Single Responsibility principle correct?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I've been starting to learn SOLID principles today and wanted some advice on if I really have understood the S principle (Single Reposibility) correctly.

Before I implemented the S principle, my code was this.

```
class Engine : Engine
{
    public void Start()
    {
        // business logic...
    }
}

class Car 
{
    private readonly Engine _engine;

    public Car(Engine engine)
    {
        _engine = engine;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _engine.VerifyEngine();
        _engine.CheckHeat();
        _engine.Start();
    }   
}
```

After implementing the S rule my code was this. Notice I've also reduced coupling with the Engine class and used an IEngine.

```
interface IEngine
{
    void Start();
}

class Engine : IEngine
{
    public void Start()
    {
        _engine.VerifyEngine();
        _engine.CheckHeat();
        // business logic...
    }
}

class Car 
{
    private readonly IEngine _engine;

    public Car(IEngine engine)
    {
        _engine = engine;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _engine.Start();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a different stackexchange website: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Are my thoughts on the Single Responsibility principle correct?" How should we know? you didn't share your thoughts with us... Where is what Wikipedia have to say about [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: Uncle Bob (Robert C Martin) desribes SRP as "only one reason to change" http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod. His talks in this regards can be very helpful. I find this answer a good example of SRP: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150781/172951. The activity of fishing is a single responsibility (to catch fish) but requires multiple elements. You should research the underlining point of SRP, in this case your car, using a key, within the ignition, spark plugs and ignition leads... have a single responsibility to start the engine.

Answer (score 0):

Two remarks:

- the key change for S-principle was your decision to put the engine initialisation details in the Start() method of the engine class itself. Good.
- it is also a sound S-principle decision to introduce an IEngine interface. Doing so, you can let any "Engine" class do its own work, without "Car" having to bother about its internals. The only thing the car needs to know is that it may Start() the Engine.

One thing you will need to change is the way VerifyEngine() and CheckHeat() are referred to. Your setup will not compile, because there is no _engine property in your Engine class. VerifyEngine() and CheckHeat() are actually private methods of Engine.

Also, your two Engine status verifications could yield a boolean result and Start() could also yield a boolean result, like so:

```
class Engine : IEngine
{
  private bool VerifyEngine()
  { return true; }

  private bool CheckHeat()
  { return true; }

  public bool Start()
  {
    if (VerifyEngine() && CheckHeat())
    {
      // business logic...
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use exceptions to express exceptional behaviour, not boolean results. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159096/return-magic-value-throw-exception-or-return-false-on-failure

Comment: I read your link. You are right for "exceptional behaviour" that has to do with the usual coding suspects like missing data, zero pointers, outrange or divide zero, I agree with you. When a result is as designed (engine may start or not), it should be boolean, or any other relevant result.. Please keep in mind this question is not about coding details, it is about design decisions..

Comment: I'm sorry for you with a car which may or may not start. Mine does every time. Otherwise I regard it as _broken_, which is exceptional.

Comment: What does indicators have to do with an engine, which may not start in a non-exceptional case? Thus I'd prefer naming the method TryStart() to express it's possible negative outcome. When something called Start executed normally, I regard the objects as _started_. When something called TryStart executed, I assume that an attempt was made to start something and that I maybe have result telling me about the state.